# Unique field validation with FeatherJS and Joi

Tags: feathersjs, joi, nedb

With FeatherJS, I defined a users model like this:

```js
import NeDB from 'nedb';
import path from 'path';
import { Application } from '../declarations';

export default function (app: Application): NeDB {
  const dbPath = app.get('nedb');
  const Model = new NeDB({
    filename: path.join(dbPath, 'users.db'),
    autoload: true,
  });

  Model.ensureIndex({
    fieldName: 'email',
    unique: true,
  });

  return Model;
}
```

And I ensure some validation thanks to Joi on the user hooks:

```js
import * as feathersAuthentication from '@feathersjs/authentication';
import * as local from '@feathersjs/authentication-local';
import { disallow } from 'feathers-hooks-common';
import Joi from '@hapi/joi';
import { validate } from '../../hooks';

const { authenticate } = feathersAuthentication.hooks;
const { hashPassword, protect } = local.hooks;

const validation = validate(
  Joi.object({
    email: Joi.string().email().alter({
      create: (schema) => schema.required(),
    }),
    password: Joi.string().min(8).alter({
      create: (schema) => schema.required(),
    }),
  }),
);

export default {
  before: {
    all: [],
    find: [
      authenticate('jwt'),
    ],
    get: [
      authenticate('jwt'),
    ],
    create: [
      validation,
      hashPassword('password'),
    ],
    update: disallow(),
    patch: [
      hashPassword('password'),
      authenticate('jwt'),
    ],
    remove: [
      authenticate('jwt'),
    ],
  },

  // ...
};
```

The Joi validation is working, producing bad request error if the submitted data is not valid.

The unique index prevent users to create an account with an already existing email address, but it produce a basic 500 error instance, difficult to exploit on my front app.

Is there a way to handle unique validation with Joi, or should I rethink my logic?

Note: I'm using NeDB here, but moving to Mongo is also possible.

Answer (score 1):

I faced this problem too. The way I got around this is by accessing the service from the hook to check if an account with the same email already exists.

In your hook, add something like.

```
const userService = context.app.service(“users”);// get the users service
const result = await userService.find({query: {email: context.data.email }});
if (result.total > 0) { // throw an error because an account already exists.}
```

This solution works for me as it’s decoupled from any kind of database or package.

What we are doing here is asking the users service if a user with the same email already exists using the service’s `find()`method. If the service returns a record, that is `result.total > 0` the service already has a user with the same email. So, we throw an exception.

You can learn more about querying services [here](https://docs.feathersjs.com/api/databases/querying.html)

Comment: Thanks. I was indeed thinking about something like that, but I would like to know if a less manual method is possible.

Comment: @Soullivaneuh To be honest, a less manual solution would involve some kind of coupling to a specific stack, as you’ll need to be able to query the user database to check for uniqueness. One other option is to check at the database level by doing something like `email: {unique: true}` in a Mongoose model. The downside is your coupling validation logic at the data layer. But that’s an option.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't say that as a truth. In fact, I'm quite new on the NodeJS env so I'm learning. ;-)